# Using android.hardware.camera2

Tags: android, camera

For some reason Android Studio doesn't find the new camera library: [android.hardware.camera2](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)

Do you have any suggestions? The code looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you `camera2` is package name not class name

see [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html)

You must call `import android.hardware.camera2.*;` to import all calss from `camera2` Api

Comment: Also, your `compileSdkVersion` would need to be 21 or higher, otherwise the package (and its classes) will not exist.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Camera class in new package for Camera i.e. android.hardware.camera2.
To use Camera class use the deprecated package android.hardware.Camera.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.hardware.camera2.*;
```

is different from

```
Camera camera; //this one uses android.hardware.Camera.*;
```

see the android.hardware.Camera and android.hardware.camera2 documentation.

This is some example classes available on camera2 to be used on the new API 21+

```
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
```